# Решение погрешности в вычислениях

Tags: php, математика

Всем привет. Делаю алгоритм биржи, который определяет нужную сумму и коэффициент 2 игрока исходя из суммы и коэффициента 1 игрока.

```
class Bet{
   //Поиск коэффициента 2 игрока
    public function findCoefficient($other_coefficient){
        return round($other_coefficient / ($other_coefficient - 1),2);
    }
    //Определяет прибыль 1 игрока - что также является нужной, стартовой суммой 2 игрока
    public function findProfit($money, $coefficient){
        return round($money * $coefficient-$money, 2);  
    }
    //Вывод игрока
    public function findOutcome($money, $coefficient){
        return round($money * $coefficient,2);  
    }
 }
```

Задача предоставлять данные с максимумом в 2 знаках после точки (2.30). Но используя round(num,2). Все вычисления сбиваются.

```
$money1P = 7433;
$cof1P = 1.15;

$cof2Player = $bet->findCoefficient($cof1P);
$money2Player = $bet->findProfit($money1P, $cof1P);
$bet->findOutcome($money1P, $cof1P); // 8547.95
$bet->findOutcome($money2Player, $cof2Player); //8551.67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Округляйте значения только когда вам нужно их выводить.

Округляя при каждой операции, вы убиваете точность вычислений.